# Is it possible to define the issue number in GitHub?

Tags: api, github, github-api, redmine-api

I would like to move from Redmine to GitHub by importing my repositories and issues.

In my commits I referenced issues by using issues numbers like #343.

Since issues number are cross project inside Redmine, I would like to change issue id in GitHub to match the same as in Redmine.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. You create an issue by POSTing to `/repos/:owner/:repo/issues`. You can set `title`, `body`, `assignee`, `milestone`, and `labels` - that's it.

You might want to instead append the Redmine issue number to the GitHub title, like:

> Button doesn't click [Redmine #1234]

You could also link to the old issue in the `body` of the issue.

See the [create an issue API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) for more details.

If that's not good enough, you should know that issue#s are auto-incrementing, so you could keep the number by POSTing them in the correct order, and POSTing and DELETEing throwaway issues for gaps in the sequence.